# How to close socks listener for 127.0.0.1:9050?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, proxy

After getting my web server setup, I'm trying to finish a test hidden service. I'm receiving the error: "*Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use [WSAEADDRINUSE ]. Is Tor already running?*"

How can you manually close the existing listener so there aren't two connections trying to be established? I'm using Powershell, Windows 10. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's a windows 10 bug - it binds some of system services to it - and I bet it's done on purpose! Just choose another port - I used 9999 or 19999 - and it worked well. Microsoft has it's affiliations with a privacy-invading state structures, you know - so it was quite an unpleasant surprise for me too like a year+ ago. Just change the port - and that's it.

Comment: I ended up here after installing Tor from my Ubuntu. So the answer is not good at all imo.

For me its about now to find out which Linux service is blocking the port :(

Comment: As it was stated on the question body - it's a windows specific case. And the answer is fitting windows well: I've experienced this exact problem myself after some windows update - it looks like it was introduced on purpose by Microsoft at some point of time. And the most painless solution is stated here - trust me, I've tried to disable or reconfigure the service, to run Tor as a service before it, e.t.c...